# Pegar tabela de URL no R

Tags: html, r, url

Preciso fazer isso aqui:

```
library(xml)

URL <- "http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/"

tabela1 <- readHTMLTable(URL, which = 1, colClasses = )

tabela1$V3 <- NULL

names(tabela1) <- c("Posição","Time")

tabela2 <- readHTMLTable(URL, which = 2)

tabela2$`ÚLT. JOGOS` <- NULL

df.data <- bind_cols(tabela1, tabela2)

df.data$Time <- gsub("[A-Z]{3}$","",df.data$Time)
```

Mas sem usar a library XML, porque a aplicação que utilizo não suporta.

Comment: O problema não está claro para mim. Entendi que não é possível usar o pacote `XML`, mas isto significa que **nenhum** outro pacote pode ser utilizado? Ou seja, o problema deve ser resolvido com os comandos base do R? Ou é possível instalar outros pacotes de webscraping, como `rvest`, por exemplo?

Comment: Resumidamente, preciso extrair tabela de um URL no Rstudio, posso somente utilizar pacotes existentes no **R**, mas sem utilizar XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como comentado pelo @MarcusNunes, é possível fazer esta extração utilizando o [`rvest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/):

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "http://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/"
tabelas <- read_html(URL) %>% html_table()

tabela1 <- tabelas[[1]]
tabela1[[3]] <- NULL
names(tabela1) <- c("Posição","Time")

tabela2 <- tabelas[[2]]
tabela2$`ÚLT. JOGOS` <- NULL

df.data <- dplyr::bind_cols(tabela1, tabela2)
df.data$Time <- gsub("[A-Z]{3}$","",df.data$Time)
```

Se houver a limitação com uso de pacotes, apenas com o `r-base` é possível criar seu próprio `html_table2`:

```
pagina <- readLines(URL, encoding = 'UTF-8')

html_table2 <- function(pagina) {
  tabelas <- strsplit(paste(pagina, collapse = "\n"), '<table.*?>')[[1]]
  # remover lixo antes da primeira tabela
  tabelas <- tabelas[-1]

  tabelas_limpas <- lapply(tabelas, function(x) {
    # tirar sujeira posterior a '</table>'
    limpa <- sub('</table>.*', '', x)
  })

  linhas <- lapply(tabelas_limpas, function(x) {
    linhas <- strsplit(x, '<tr.*?>')[[1]]
    sub('</tr.*?>', '', linhas)
  })

  df <- lapply(linhas, function(x) {
    colunas <- lapply(x, function(y) strsplit(y, '<td.*?>')[[1]])
    matriz <- do.call(rbind, colunas)
    limpas <- gsub('</?.+?>', '', matriz) # Remove tags HTML
    limpas <- gsub('\\n', '', limpas)
    limpas <- gsub('[\\s]{2,}', '', limpas)
    # Remove duas primeiras linhas e a primeira e ultima colunas
    limpas <- limpas[- (1:2), -c(1, ncol(limpas))]
    as.data.frame(limpas)
  })
  df
}

tabelas <- html_table2(pagina)
tabela1 <- tabelas[[1]]
names(tabela1) <- c("Posição","Time")

tabela2 <- tabelas[[2]]
names(tabela2) <- c('P', 'J', 'V', 'E', 'D', 'GP', 'GC', 'SG', '%')

df.data <- dplyr::bind_cols(tabela1, tabela2)
df.data$Time <- gsub("[A-Z]{3}$","",df.data$Time)
```